# Javascript функции с перечислением

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно создать функцию такой структуры

```
sayHello({
параметр1: значение1,
параметр2: значение2
});

.draggable({
 handle:".class";
})
```

Как в JqueryUI. Как сделать такую функцию и как с ней работать где объявлять объект и.т.д.

Comment: `function test (arg) { alert(arg.значение1);
    alert(arg.значение2);}`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский наверно, все-таки `arg.параметр1`, а не `значение1`?

Comment: @Yaant угу. поспешишь, как говорится...)

Comment: приведи пример функции `jQuery UI`, о которой ты говоришь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял, вам нужна функция, которая в качестве аргумента принимает объект, перечисляет его параметры и делает с ними что-то еще.
Эта функция перечисляет параметры объекта (obj) и по очереди выводит их в alert.

```
sayHello({
  word1: 'hello',
  word2: 'word,',
  word3: 'javascript,',
  word4: 'and',
  word5: 'etc'
});

function sayHello(obj) { //сама функция
  var str = ''; // переменная, в которую записываются слова
  for (var key in obj) { //перечисление параметров объекта
    str += obj[key] + ' ';
  }
  alert(str);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо но немного подожду может еще будут ответы скорее вас и награжу

Answer (score 1):

Добавить что-то к предыдущему ответу будет сложно, действительно, функция просто принимает один параметр - объект, в котором содержатся уже все необходимые переменные. Могу только подсказать, как можно организовать дефолтные значения, для полей, которые были не указаны в объекте-параметре

```
var defaultParams = {
  param1: 'param1',
  param2: 'param2',
  param3: 'param3'
}
function someFoo(args) {
  var params = Object.assign({}, defaultParams, args)
  // если есть Jquery
  // var params = $.extend({}, defaultParams, args)

  console.log(params)
}

someFoo()
// { param1: 'param1', param2: 'param2', param3: 'param3' }

someFoo({param1: 'hello'})
// { param1: 'hello', param2: 'param2', param3: 'param3' }

someFoo({param1: 'hello', param3: 'hello3'})
// { param1: 'hello', param2: 'param2', param3: 'hello3' }
```

**PS**
`Object.assign` поддерживается не всеми браузерами, поэтому вот [полифил](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
if (!Object.assign) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(target, firstSource) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[i];
        if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
          continue;
        }

        var keysArray = Object.keys(Object(nextSource));
        for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
          var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
          var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
          if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Если подключен jQuery то вместо `var params = Object.assign({}, defaultParams, args)` можно использовать [jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/): `var params = $.extend({}, defaultParams, args)`. В таком случае отпадает необходимость полифила

Comment: а не проще сделать так

Comment: `params.param = params.param || "Default value";`

Comment: @Duoxx, а если параметров 20, для каждого писать такую строку?

Comment: спасибо за дефолтные.